# Finishing up and Arch Linux install and Grub is failing to install

Tags: linux, grub, arch-linux, grub2

Not sure what to do at this point. I finished all of the Arch Linux installer and get to the bootloader step and it fails. This is for a dual booted Windows 7/Arch laptop if that helps at all. Not sure what to try at this point. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

```
grub> device (hd0) /dev/sda
grub> root (hd0,4)
      Filesystem type unknown, partition type 0x7
grub> setup (hd0)
Error 17: Cannot mount selected partition
grub> quit
[DEBUG UI ] notify: Error installing GRUB. (see /dev/tty7 for output)
```

Results of fdisk -l /dev/sda

```
/dev/sda4 Id: fm System: W95 Ext'd (LBA)
```

Results of parted /dev/sda p

```
Numbers 4 and 5 are identical, other than the type. 4 is extended, 5 is logical.         
Also for type, 4 is lba and 5 has no type.
```

Comment: Nate, please provide more detail about the error you are seeing.  "It fails" does not provide us with any way to help.

Comment: @Paul, I'd like to, but I'm not sure how to get to the file it is telling me to look at. /dev/tty7. How can I access that through the Arch install process?

Comment: What exactly is it saying?  You can get to /dev/tty7 by hitting ctrl-alt-7

Comment: @Paul, 

    grub> device (hd0) /dev/sda
    grub> root (hd0,4)
          Filesystem type unknown, partition type 0x7
    grub> setup (hd0)
    Error 17: Cannot mount selected partition
    grub> quit
    [DEBUG UI ] notify: Error installing GRUB. (see /dev/tty7 for output)

Comment: Well it looks like the problem is that arch is trying to suggest that your root is in `hd0,4`, but that is an NTFS partition.  Looks like we are going to have to install grub manually.  Can you add to your question the results of `fdisk -l /dev/sda` `parted /dev/sda p` and `cat /boot/grub/menu.lst`

Comment: @Paul, Results posted. Obviously not copy/paste, as I can't do that. Is that enough? I didn't feel like typing out my whole menu.lst.

Comment: Can you clarify - are you saying that `fdisk` can only see one partition, and parted can only see two?  If so, something is very wrong.  Can you still boot to Windows?

Comment: @Paul, it can see all of my partitions (sda1-5), I just didnt post them as they didnt seem relevant. I can still boot into Windows.